# Help identifying a vampire romance novel

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I'm trying to identify a book that I read in high school.

It was about a girl getting mugged in a dark alley. I think the mugger was a vampire who sucked most of the life out of her and, in an attempt to save herself she bites his hand thus turning herself into a vampire.

Another vampire was watching the whole thing and knew she would need saving since new vampires can't control their blood lust when new.

In order to keep her alive he has her locked up in a cage and allows her to feed off of him. I remember him being of Russian decent and calling her "beautiful" in his native language, as a pet name.

Comment: FYI : Beautiful in Russian is "krasivyy"

Comment: FYI: Since he would be referring to a girl, it would actually be "krasivaya" or "krasavitsa". No idea what the story is though.